# Make javascript execute linearly

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am building a game. When a piece is moved ('.draggable'), I need make the first ajax call (to move_script.php) which will validate the move and then save it in a database. After that is done, I want to run the second ajax call (to past_moves.php) and query the database and write out the new move.
My problem, is that sometimes the second ajax calls pulls out the results BEFORE the current move is there. I've used microtime(); in the php code to see what is happening, and every time that the most recent result isn't pulled, the second ajax script is completing first. (Most of the time the most recent result comes out, but every so often it won't, it seems to be randomly, every 5 - 15 times or so).
How can I ensure that the second ajax call won't run until the first one is done?

Thank you

code:

```
<script>
            $(function() {

              $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ 

                  stop: function(event, ui) {
                      var start = $(this).attr('id')

                      //ajax call number 1
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "../move_script.php",
                          data: { start: start }
                        }).done(function( msg ) {
                          //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                          $("#chessboard").html(msg);
                        }); 

                 //ajax call number 2   
                 $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "../past_moves.php",
                       data: {}
                     }).done(function( moves ) {
                   $("#past_moves").html( moves );
                     });
                   }
              });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the ajax calls

```
//ajax call number 1
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../move_script.php",
    data: { start: start }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    $("#chessboard").html(msg);
    //ajax call number 2   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../past_moves.php",
            data: {}
        }).done(function( moves ) {
            $("#past_moves").html( moves );
        });
    });
});
```

This nesting will force the second call to wait until the first has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Put the second ajax call in the callback of the first ajax call to make sure it only executes after it is complete.  Otherwise, since ajax is asynchronous, it starts the request and then keeps going (in this case, starting the second ajax). I'm not familiar with the "done" method - maybe you can put it in that function that you already have.  Otherwise, this is the syntax I'm familiar with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../move_script.php",
    data: { start: start },
    success: function(data){
        //data is whatever the ajax returns.  is it msg in this case?
        //put second ajax call here
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //might not need here, but this is example of callback which will be executed instead of success if server returns an error
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        //another useful callback to know about - will execute after success or error
    }
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/